# How to use sftp within Nautilus?

Tags: 14.04, nautilus, sftp

Since I have migrated to Ubuntu 14.04, I am unable to access sftp through Nautilus. If I enter `sftp://user@sshserver` in Nautilus (Ctrl+L), I get the following error message:

> Sorry, could not display all the contents of "vmalep (sftp)": The
> specified location is not supported.

I'm very confused because it was working with the same server and with the previous version. I have the same problem accessing another ssh server laptop in the same LAN.

Answer (score 4):

In order to have the `sftp://` protocol handled by Nautilus you first need a virtual filesystem provided by the `gvfs-backends` package. Just install this package and retry:

```
sudo apt-get install gvfs-backends
```

If you want more information:

- https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/gvfs

Comment: it is installed but still "you don't have permission to access the requested location"?

Comment: I had the "timeout" issue. My mistake was that I mistyped the hostname ip address. It worked fine when I corrected it.